# Magento - Custom Options are added for each storeview

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.8

I have the following problem:

I want to add custom options to my magento product programmatically.
This works so far, BUT the options are added multiple times, more accurate one time for each store view I have, but they are all visible in each storeview.
I only need ONE option for the Default View. Here is the code I use:

```
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', 1234);

    if(!$product) {
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
    } else {
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product->getId());
    }
    $customOpt = array(
            'is_delete'         => 0,
            'is_require'        => true,
            'title'             => 'ProcessingImport',
            'type'              => 'drop_down',
            'price_type'        => 'fixed',
            'price'             => 0,
            'sort_order'        => 0,
            'values'            => array(
                    array(
                            'is_delete'         => 0,
                            'title'             => 'Import ' . rand(10, 100),
                            'price_type'        => 'fixed',
                            'price'             => 0,
                            'sku'               => 'SKUImportOne',
                            'option_type_id'    => -1
                    ),
                    array(
                            'is_delete'         => 0,
                            'title'             => 'Import ' . rand(10, 100),
                            'price_type'        => 'fixed',
                            'price'             => 0,
                            'sku'               => 'SKUImportTwo',
                            'option_type_id'    => -1
                    )
            ),
    );
    $product->setCanSaveCustomOptions(true);
    $product->setProductOptions(array($customOpt));
    $product->save();
```

Does someone have any idea why it is added multiple times for each view?
Here is an image where you can see my problem:

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution in my code.
After the code posted above I have a loop, where I set several prices for different stores. And magento is so "smart" that it saves all options again for each store.
I placed the code-snipped AFTER this loop and the option is only created once.